# How to get the print of 3 values?

Tags: arrays, printing

I want to get prints of `mini`, `maxi`, and `a8_1`, but, instead, I just got the last print.

```
a8_1 = [-0.7, -1.5, -1.7, 0.3, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]

a8_1 = np.array(a8_1)

a8_1

mini = a8_1.min()

mini

maxi = a8_1.max()

maxi
```

Comment: i want to get prints of min maxi and a8_1. instead of i just got the last print...

Comment: What language are you using? Python?

Comment: You should add more details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using interactive shell, and have already imported the numpy package (which I do not see in the code above), this above code should definitely print all 3.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a8_1 = [-0.7, -1.5, -1.7, 0.3, 1.5, 1.8, 2.0]
>>> a8_1 = np.array(a8_1)
>>> a8_1
array([-0.7, -1.5, -1.7,  0.3,  1.5,  1.8,  2. ])
>>> mini = a8_1.min()
>>> 
>>> mini
-1.7
>>> maxi = a8_1.max()
>>> maxi
2.0
>>>
```